# Limit left join to first record chronologically

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to perform a left join where I limit the joins to the first record that matches in chronological order.

The below example matches all records. Is there a way to limit the left join to only a single record ordered chronologically? Essentially, only match the first sale associated with the customer?

```
select *
from customer_table
   left join (
       select sales_item_id, sales_date
       from sales_table
       order by sales_date asc
)
on customer_table.customer_id = sales_table.customer_id
```

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a window dunfuction to get the first record, or the last or the third for that matter

```
select *
from customer_table c
   left join (
       select customer_id ,sales_item_id, sales_date,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER By sales_date asc) rn
       from sales_table
) s
on c.customer_id = s.customer_id and s.rn = 1
```